SAP ABAP infoset union query
I have 2 tables in SAP and I want to perform a union between both of them. In essence, I want to have the rows of the second query under the first one. It's worth noting that they have different columns but there is common ID column between them, I need to do this query inside an infoset (Tcode SQ02). I'm completely new to ABAP so if something can provide me some guidance, it would be much appreciated.
From what I understand, I can't use the Union operator inside infosets so I'm not sure how else to do it. Is this even possible at all?

There's an official online documentation "InfoSets" (in SAP Query technology) which answers your questions.

Hi @SandraRossi, thanks for answering. I'm looking at this documentation but I cant find anything on unions. Do you refer to a specific page?

The documentations can't say what is not possible (that would be endless), they say what is possible, so it must be read thoroughly. ABAP is Turing-complete, it can do "anything" (unions for instance).
